# Pandas merge dataframes with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes and have a problem in figuring out how, as it is not straigh forward.
One data frame has match results for over 25000 games and looks like this.
The second one has team performance metrics but only for around 1500 games.
As I am not allowed to post pictures yet, here are the column names of interest:

```
df_match['date', 'home_team_api_id', 'away_team_api_id']
df_team_attributes['date', 'team_api_id']
```

Both data frames have additional columns with results or performance metrics.
To be able to merge correctly, I need to merge by date and by looking if the 'team_api_id' matches either 'home...' or 'away_team_api_id'

This is what I have tried until now:

```
df_team_performance = pd.merge(df_team_attributes, df_match,
                               how = 'left',
                               left_on = ['date', 'team_api_id', 'team_api_id'],
                               right_on = ['date', 'home_team_api_id', 'home_team_api_id'])
```

I have tried also with only 2 columns, but w/o succes.
What I would like to get is a new data frame with only the rows of the df_team_attributes and columns from both data frames.
Thank you in advance!

Added to request by Correlien:
output of `print(df_match[['date', 'home_team_api_id', 'away_team_api_id', 'win_home', 'win_away', 'draw', 'win']].head(10).to_dict())`
{'date': {0: '2008-08-17 00:00:00', 1: '2008-08-16 00:00:00', 2: '2008-08-16 00:00:00', 3: '2008-08-17 00:00:00', 4: '2008-08-16 00:00:00', 5: '2008-09-24 00:00:00', 6: '2008-08-16 00:00:00', 7: '2008-08-16 00:00:00', 8: '2008-08-16 00:00:00', 9: '2008-11-01 00:00:00'}, 'home_team_api_id': {0: 9987, 1: 10000, 2: 9984, 3: 9991, 4: 7947, 5: 8203, 6: 9999, 7: 4049, 8: 10001, 9: 8342}, 'away_team_api_id': {0: 9993, 1: 9994, 2: 8635, 3: 9998, 4: 9985, 5: 8342, 6: 8571, 7: 9996, 8: 9986, 9: 8571}, 'win_home': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 1}, 'win_away': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'draw': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'win': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}}

output for `print(df_team_attributes[['date', 'team_api_id', 'buildUpPlaySpeed', 'buildUpPlaySpeedClass']].head(10).to_dict())`
{'date': {0: '2010-02-22 00:00:00', 1: '2014-09-19 00:00:00', 2: '2015-09-10 00:00:00', 3: '2010-02-22 00:00:00', 4: '2011-02-22 00:00:00', 5: '2012-02-22 00:00:00', 6: '2013-09-20 00:00:00', 7: '2014-09-19 00:00:00', 8: '2015-09-10 00:00:00', 9: '2010-02-22 00:00:00'}, 'team_api_id': {0: 9930, 1: 9930, 2: 9930, 3: 8485, 4: 8485, 5: 8485, 6: 8485, 7: 8485, 8: 8485, 9: 8576}, 'buildUpPlaySpeed': {0: 60, 1: 52, 2: 47, 3: 70, 4: 47, 5: 58, 6: 62, 7: 58, 8: 59, 9: 60}, 'buildUpPlaySpeedClass': {0: 'Balanced', 1: 'Balanced', 2: 'Balanced', 3: 'Fast', 4: 'Balanced', 5: 'Balanced', 6: 'Balanced', 7: 'Balanced', 8: 'Balanced', 9: 'Balanced'}}

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df_match[['date', 'home_team_api_id', 'away_team_api_id']].head(10).to_dict())` and `print(df_team_attributes[['date', 'team_api_id']].to_dict())` for your code to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried casting the your date columns into the correct format and then attempting the merge? The following worked for me based on the example that you provided -

```
# Casting to date
df_match["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_match["date"])
df_team_attributes["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_match["date"])

# Merging on the date field alone
df_team_performance = pd.merge(df_team_attributes, df_match,
                               how = 'left',
                               on = 'date')

# Filtering out the required rows
result = df_team_performance.query("(team_api_id == home_team_api_id) | (team_api_id == away_team_api_id)")
```

Please let me know if my understanding of your question is correct.

Comment: Well, thank you, it almost does the job.
I did in the meantime convert date and, when I merge the 2 dataframes, the resulting one has 6800 rows, as i suppose that on the dates where team_attributes have been recorded, there have been more matches.
But, when I am performing the query, I only get 50 rows, wich can not be true.

Comment: Your solution is good, thank you.
I was surpized by the number of rows remaining, but I have tried a couple of them manually and it apears to be true.
Thank you!